# Most '.onion' links won't load?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-routing

OS: Kali Linux Live

Settings have not been modified.

Most '.onion' links that I try to access simply refuse to load. They will hang on the loading screen until the connection times out. Not all of them refuse to load, some of them actually do load. The websites I am trying to access are websites that have pretty a good uptime and are used quite often. You know, like, mainstream websites, but for the dark web.

The website that I especially need to access right now is Torum. It's link changed. The previous link worked fine, but now the new one just doesn't work, for some odd reason, regardless of being on the same server.

Any ideas as to why this would be happening? Is anyone else having this issue?

***Log:***

```
1/7/20, 18:26:08.382 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay
1/7/20, 18:26:08.382 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay
1/7/20, 18:26:08.461 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15% (handshake_done): Handshake with a relay done
1/7/20, 18:26:08.462 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 75% (enough_dirinfo): Loaded enough directory info to build circuits
1/7/20, 18:26:08.462 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90% (ap_handshake_done): Handshake finished with a relay to build circuits
1/7/20, 18:26:08.462 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 95% (circuit_create): Establishing a Tor circuit
1/7/20, 18:26:09.640 [WARN] Our clock is 4 hours, 33 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2020-01-07 23:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings!
1/7/20, 18:26:09.640 [WARN] Received microdesc flavor consensus with skewed time (CONSENSUS): It seems that our clock is behind by 4 hours, 33 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings.
1/7/20, 18:26:09.640 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 95% (circuit_create): Establishing a Tor circuit. (Clock skew -16432 in microdesc flavor consensus from CONSENSUS; CLOCK_SKEW; count 1; recommendation warn; host ? at ?)
1/7/20, 18:26:09.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100% (done): Done
1/7/20, 18:26:09.710 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
1/7/20, 18:26:09.710 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
1/7/20, 18:26:09.710 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
1/7/20, 18:26:41.178 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
1/7/20, 18:26:41.178 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
1/7/20, 18:26:41.178 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
1/7/20, 18:26:41.178 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
1/7/20, 18:26:41.178 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
1/7/20, 18:26:42.284 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
1/7/20, 18:26:42.383 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Most onion services are not running on servers. The are running on PC's, laptops, raspberry pi's etc. If the person running it turns off their machine, then the website is down.

Troubleshooting an onion service is just like any other website. If you can get to onion site A but not onion site B, C, or D it is because those are down.

http://expyuzz4wqqyqhjn.onion/ is the site that I use as a test. If it is up, and another site is down, then I know that Tor is working but the other website isn't.

Comment: Well, right now, Torch will load, but the website you linked won't. I can access certain websites from some devices, but not from others. I don't know. Tor just seems to be broken. :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to fix your clock - you have a severe warning in your logs:

```
1/7/20, 18:26:09.640 [WARN] Our clock is 4 hours, 33 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2020-01-07 23:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings!
```

It's either your client PC is not using NTP - or you've got hit by ISP bogus NTP broadcasts, many cases of that in cell networks and wifi hotspots. To make a bulletproof defense from this attack vector - use a local hardware GPS receiver with PPS, quite a cheap ones to buy almost everywhere, like AliExpress.

Also make sure that you have Tor network consensus actual: if you have this at home or a friendly place  drop a single raspberry pi or something like it to run Tor node 24/7/365 - you don't have to make it an exit! But you should, if you can ;) All you need is this node running with reachable ORPort and - it's a huge benefit - on a static IP address, but it's not lethal if you don't have it. The thing is that you're making it also a bridge for yourself even not configuring it as a bridge! It will provide you with the freshest and the widest network consensus data possible, so you will have a full connectivity to the Tor network.

Only having these two things mended should you start to have a doubt that the site is not working - trust my experience, mending these two problems I've mentioned upstrings - revived some grave-like setups. It works and it's simple to do by hand