# Why there is always a network down when I try to access the onion site?

Tags: onion-services

I am able to access the DuckDuckGo but it is not able for me to access hidden wiki and other onion sites. I wish someone can help me fix this problem! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

See [Most Onion Links Won't Load](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/20780/most-onion-links-wont-load/20781#20781). You can also attempt to change your circuit but nothing can help a website that is down or has changed it's address.